# Adding UUID to XML request in the servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, uuid

I am trying to write a servlet that returns a data in xml format. And I am trying to generate a unique ID for that particular request and as soon as I try to add that `uuid` in the XML request I am always getting a following error on the browser-

```
   This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 14: AttValue: " or ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

This is how my code looks like-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");     
    System.out.println("uuid = " + uuid);

    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
    writer.println("<request uuid = "+uuid+">");
    writer.println("<app hash = \"abc\"/>");
    writer.println("<app hash = \"def\"/>");
    writer.println("</request>");
    writer.flush();
}
```

Is there any problem in my above code? Can anyone please guide me what is it I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should put your UUID under quotes:

```
writer.println("<request uuid = \""+uuid+"\">");
```

Note the extra

> \"

around uuid.

Answer (score 2):

You forget the `"` around the attribute value, change:

```
 writer.println("<request uuid = "+uuid+">");
```

to

```
 writer.println("<request uuid = \""+uuid+"\">");
```

and it should work.